# Can two functions be substantially different if their inner product is close to $1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

I have met a strange feature. Assume that I have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ defined at the interval $(-1,1)$. The question is, if the inner product of these two functions is close to $1$, are these functions "close" in some sense to each other? I thought, yes, but then considered an example:
$f(x)=(1-x^2)^{1/8}$, $g(x)=(1-x^2)^{-1/8}$. If I normalize both functions and calculate their inner product I get $0.977$. But the functions are obviously very different: $f(x)$ tends to $0$ when $x$ tends to $1$ or $-1$, while $g(x)$ tends to infinity.
Can the functions be indeed so different in spite of their inner product being almost $1$, or do I make a fundamental error somewhere?

Comment: This really depends quite a bit on what assumptions you have on your functions. What function space do they belong to? Are they supposed to be square integrable? Are you requiring something else?

Comment: *Which* inner product on $(0, 1)$? Presumably, you're looking at an integral. Is there a weight, e.g. $w$ in  
$$
\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) w(x) \, dx.
$$
The definition of the inner product determines what *close* means.

Comment: Convergence in the $L^2$ norm is very different from uniform convergence, i.e., convergence in the sup norm.

Comment: If $v\cdot v=w\cdot w=1$ and $v\cdot w=1,$ then $v,w$ are essentially equal.  This is because $(v-w)\cdot(v-w)=0.$ Without ensuring $\|v\|=\|w\|=1,$ this isn't remotely true.

Comment: More generally, you'd need: $$v\cdot w=\|v\|\cdot\|w\|.$$

Comment: Why would you normalize the functions before taking their inner product? If you consider the analog for vectors in $\Bbb R^2$, would you be surprised that $(1,0)$
 and $(10^{10},1)$, after normalize them,  have an inner product practically equal to $1$ in spite of been very different vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
\|f - g\|_2^2 = \|f\|_2^2 + \|g\|_2^2 - 2 (f,g)_2.$$
In your case,
this results in
$$
\|f - g\|_2 = \sqrt{2(1-0.977)} \approx 0.214.
$$
Thus, it seems that the functions are not very close, as you observed.

Answer (score 1):

The functions are only very different near two points in the domain
$[-1,1]$.
Over most of that domain the two functions are both close to $f(x)=1$.

The behavior of a function near an isolated point (or two) does not have as much effect on its similarity to other functions as its behavior over the rest of its domain,
at least if you are taking inner products in a typical way,
for example,
$$
\langle f, g \rangle = \int_D f(x) g(x) \, \mathrm dx.
$$

Also, is $0.977$ really close to $1$ when dealing with inner products?
If you had $\cos\theta = 0.977$ in an exercise where $\theta$ was the angle between to vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, the angle between the vectors would be more than $12.3$ degrees.